# Email log error Django on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ses

Since I migrate my django application on elastic beanstalk I no longer receive any error log email due to a 500 error.

I am using amazon Simple Email Service to send email.

What should I set to receive this kind of email?

Comment: You will need to any relevant code or configuration to your question in order for someone to sufficiently answer your question.

Comment: @jbird I did add any code because this a basic django application. I am just receiving "Invalid HTTP_HOST header" error.

Comment: Thank you @alexandresaiz. I am already using sparkpost for transactional email. I am speaking about django emails generated after a 500 error.

Comment: Have you properly configured the SES service in your AWS account, and requested to have your account taken out of SES sandbox mode? Do the EC2 instances in your Elastic Beanstalk app have the appropriate IAM instance profiles assigned that give them access to SES? Are there any logs on the server indicating an error when attempting to send emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this mistakes because I haven't got defined the `LOGGING` variables in my `setings.py` file.

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
    'null': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {  # send email on error 500
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.security.DisallowedHost': {  # exception for disallow host
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
}
```

Thanks guys for your comments.